# How to avoid the overflow of div without getting cropped by the margin of parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to stop the [overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gBPW.png) of a div just at the end of the view port.

Here's the code:

HTML

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main>
      <section class="hero">
        <div class="cat-container">
          <div class="cat">
            <img src="img/cat.png" alt="cat" />
            <div class="inner-circle"></div>
            <div class="outer-circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFFBF3;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 2em;
}

.hero {
  margin-top: 6.5em;
}

.cat {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;

  img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    height: 247px;

    transform: translate(-36%, -35%);
  }

  .inner-circle, .outer-circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .inner-circle {
    z-index: -1;

    width: 305px;
    height: 305px;

    background-color: #FFEBC3;

    transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  }

  .outer-circle {
    z-index: -2;

    width: 573px;
    height: 573px;

    background-color: white;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

I tried to put `overflow-x: hidden;` in `.cat`,

```css
.cat {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* ... */
}
```

And in `.wrapper`

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 2em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

How ever the white div `.outer-circle` gets [cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfi8D.png) by the margin of `.wrapper`.

The only way I figured was to put `overflow-x: hidden;` in the body tag, however I think this is bad practice(?). I want to tackle the specific problem, it felt like hiding it.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Is there a reason that the cat and the inner circle aren't centred within the wrapper? Why for example translate(-36%, -35%);?

Comment: Not really, just wanted the cat a little bit to the right and the inner circle a little bit down. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cat {    
  position: relative; 
  height: 450px;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: As I stated above I already tried this and the circles get cropped beyond what I wanted by the margin of `.wrapper`. See the image in `cropped`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).